# Consultar en un diccionario MongoDB anidado

Tags: mongodb, diccionarios

Estoy tratando de aprender a filtrar los diccionarios anidados en la base de datos de MongoDB. Todos los documentos tienen la misma estructura que este ejemplo que intentaré conseguir:

[image]

Intento obtener el documento gracias al "Nombre" que es "Mi Burberry - Eau de Parfum":

```
{ "q0.Results": {"Name":"My Burberry - Eau de Parfum"} }
```

Pero no me devuelve nada:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se realizó una prueba en la siguiente colección, que tiene una estructura similar a la que nos compartes(omiti varias llaves):
[image: Colecccion Altas]

El query que funcionó fue el siguiente:

```
{"reviews.0.reviewer_name":"Izabella"}
```

En la interface Atlas:
[image: Interface filter de MongoDB Atlas]

En el caso que presentas, lo que se me ocurre es:

- Colocar la llave a filtrar del documento
- Luego, el nombre de la llave del array anidado
- Después, el índice del mismo
- Finalmente, el nombre de la llave del objeto anidado

El query:

```
{ "q0.Results.0.Name": "My Burberry - Eau de Parfum"}
```

En algunas sesiones, la herramienta `filter` me dice que no estoy ingresando los parametros de busqueda correctamente, cuando eso pasa le doy un **refresh** a la página y ya se corrige.